# why is document.querySelector never used

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering why nobody uses `document.querySelector("#myDiv");` instead of `document.getElementById("myDiv");`?

Is there browser compatibility issues, or what is the reason?

thanks

Comment: I use it so it's clearly not nobody.

Comment: ...what is the basis to believe that "nobody uses"?

Comment: I use it all the time, however, the case you're comparing I would use `getElementById` as well because `querySelector` has to figure out what you're selector means, is it a class, an id, does it contain pseudo selectors? Most people use it when they need a complex selector ran, but only want the first result (instead of `querySelectorAll`)

Comment: ok, sorry about the assumptions then, I just always see posts on stackexchange and w3schools pages only use document.getElementById(),

Comment: It makes really no performance difference.... And you can always look up the compatibility support on MDN.

Comment: Rather than saying "nobody", maybe you could provide examples of where you are seeing `getElementById` used? Saying "I just always see posts" is not very helpful.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Premise

To validate your premise, I checked StackOverflow answers with a score of 4 or higher since January...and you are right.

- 42 answers use `document.querySelector` exclusively
- 167 answers use `document.getElementById` exclusively

You can try the queries yourself at [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

#### querySelector

```
select count(*)
from Posts
where Body like '%document.querySelector(%'
and Body not like '%document.getElementById(%'
and PostTypeId = 2 -- Answer
and Score > 4
and CreationDate > '2017-01-01'
and CreationDate < '2017-08-01'
```

#### getElementById

```
select count(*)
from Posts
where Body like '%document.getElementById(%'
and Body not like '%document.querySelector(%'
and PostTypeId = 2 -- Answer
and Score > 4
and CreationDate > '2017-01-01'
and CreationDate < '2017-08-01'
```

### Answer

Now to answer you question, it's tough to say why one might favor a syntax. [Performance](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector) might be a concern (as  2pha pointed out) because `querySelector()` has to parse a string to determine which element will match, where `getElementById` doesn't need to parse the input string and can immediately query the DOM.

However, its not good practice to be querying the DOM multiple times so this usually happens once and you would keep a reference to that DOM element.

It probably comes down to the following:

- w3schools is for beginners so theres no need to introduce css selectors when you are first learning javascript
- stackoverflow has people who have used javascript before `querySelector` existed and the only option was `getElementById` so some of it is just habbit

Comment: yeah, thanks, that makes perfect sense, thankyou for your time :)